# How can I trace and debug my asm 8086 program?

Tags: assembly

Is there any software ON WINDOWS 10 that can help me trace and debug asm programs? I've tried to create a Linux VM just to use gdb but I'm wondering if there's a quicker and easier process.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_gcc_assembler or http://asmdebugger.com/

Comment: Do you mean 16-bit 8086 real mode code? It depends on what you are debugging. Are you debugging a bootloader or a DOS EXE/COM program?

Comment: First let us know what kind of program it is, e.g.: x86 16-bit or 32-bit or 64-bit program.  Is the program in a COM format or EXE format (COFF or ELF) or something else entirely....  Does the program call functions in BIOS or in a specific OS ?

Comment: I'm debugging a DOS exe.

Comment: If debugging a DOS EXE I'd recommend just getting DOSBOX and install a copy of the Turbo Debugger inside DOSBox (You can get a copy of Turbo C++ with the debugger - the debugger is called TD.EXE)

Comment: Do you really mean 8086 not x86?  Everyone's assuming 16-bit DOS because you said 8086, but you also mentioned creating a Linux VM for GDB (which would be useless for 16-bit code).  Is this hand-written asm part of a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows process?

Comment: It is 16-bit DOS. I mentioned linux gdb as it was the only way I knew of debugging asm code. Sorry to create confusion.

Answer (score -2):

If you really need to debug Linux programs in Windows GUI then VisualGDB should suit your needs:

See:
https://visualgdb.com/